# Brand new MacBook Pro with Retina display - Mail, Preview and App Store freezes on launch

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance, applications

I can never use most Apple-made apps on my MacBook Pro with Retina display, as the UI never responds, however Mail gets new emails and Preview displays images. It's just that I cannot click.

I can't close it and I can't use the menu bar, however it responds to keyboard commands.

I have to force quit these apps every single time. I don't have the 'reopen windows' option on, so I don't understand what is going on. Activity Monitor is normal.

Comment: Just cleared font cache in Onyx. No result.

Comment: You do not want to mess around with that--bring it to service. But if you must, publish Console log (located in your Utility folder) using (copy/paste) some 30 lines from the time stamp of relevance.

Comment: Why not? I've been using OnyX ever since Panther.

Comment: Plus, on a well known forum, I saw somebody fix the problem by doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what it was.

**Ink > Write Anywhere** was enabled, when it shouldn't. As soon as it was disabled, the affected Apple apps started working again.

I thought it was something to do with the Wacom tablet I bought, but couldn't find any connection. Now I know it was Apple's own Ink software. Maybe I shall report it as a bug.

Comment: I'm having the same thing, i didn't install ink it appeared on it own